# Laravel 5.4 get latest related model

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

Using Laravel 5.4

I have 2 tables:

coffees (columns: id, name, etc.)

roasts (columns: id, coffee_id, roast_date)

The roasts table can have many reocords for each coffee or none at all.

My relationships:

In Coffee Model:

```
public function roast()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Roast');
}
```

In Roast Model:

```
public function coffee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Coffee');
}
```

I want to get a list of all the coffees with the latest roast date for each one.

Is there a way to do it with Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to order by in related model, but it can be achieved by the query builder manually

```
Coffee::query()->join("roasts", "roasts.id=coffees.roast_id")->orderBy("roasts.date");
```

Note: Change the table names according to your database